How to Retrieve Artifacts from JFrog Artifactory into a .NET 6 Application?
I am working on a .NET 6 backend and I need to retrieve artifacts (specifically JSON files in ZIP format) from JFrog Artifactory. The workflow involves another team uploading these artifacts to Artifactory, and my task is to pull them into our .NET 6 backend and eventually make them accessible to the frontend.
Here’s what I need to understand:

Should I use JFrog CLI, REST API, or another method to retrieve the artifacts?

How should I handle the extraction and processing of the JSON files from the ZIP format once they are retrieved?

Should the artifact retrieval be part of the dotnet build process, or should it be handled separately in the CI/CD pipeline?

What are the common pitfalls or challenges when working with JFrog Artifactory in a .NET environment?


Any guidance, examples, or references would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my nuget.config file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <solution>
        <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
    <!-- <packageSources> -->
    <!--     <add key="MyProject" value="%ARTIFACTORY_NUGET_URL%" /> -->
    <!-- </packageSources> -->
    <!-- <packageSourceCredentials> -->
    <!--     <Synergy> -->
    <!--         <add key="Username" value="%ARTIFACTORY_NUGET_USERNAME%" /> -->
    <!--         <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%ARTIFACTORY_NUGET_PASSWORD%" /> -->
    <!--     </Synergy> -->
    <!-- </packageSourceCredentials> -->
</configuration>

